# Why was I let assign a null value to a bool? What's the best way to resolve this?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a Linq to SQL query very similar to the following:

```
var result = (from shareclass in database.ShareClassInfo

        where shareclass.Id == ID
        select new ShareClass
                   {
                       IsOnlineListing = shareclass.IsOnlineListing
                   }
       );

var list = result.ToList();
```

When I try to create a list from the results I get the following error:

> The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type System.Boolean which is a non-nullable value type.

The reason for this is that `IsOnlineListing` is a `bool`, but the field in the database is null. So I'm effectively trying to assign a value type with a null value (which is impossible).

I think the solution to this is to make `IsOnlineListing` a nullable type, but I'm a little confused why I was let do this in the first place. I mean, the database field is defined as a `[bit] NULL` field. I thought the compiler would be smarter than to let me assign `null` value to a non-nullable type, or at least it would warn me about it.

So what I'm wondering, is if this is the correct solution? Is there another way to do this? Why wasn't the compiler able to tell me that this is or could be a problem?

Comment: Was the column Nullable or changed later on ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to change your declaration of `IsOnlineListing`

From

```
bool IsOnlineListing;
```

To

```
bool? IsOnlineListing;
```

Or do something like this

```
var result = (from shareclass in database.ShareClassInfo

    where shareclass.Id == ID
    select new ShareClass
               {
                   IsOnlineListing = shareclass.IsOnlineListing.HasValue ?
                       shareclass.IsOnlineListing.Value : false;
               }
   );

var list = result.ToList();
```

Comment: Or `IsOnlineListing = shareclass.IsOnlineListing.Value`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [nullable type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx).